# NGiNX Custom Cache param based on regex match

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, cache, http-headers, useragent

## My question(s) are as follows:

- How do I set custom variables based on regexp against a useragent?
- How do I set custom headers for the reverse-proxy request?
- How do I use these values as caching parameters?

---

### Details:

I'm doing an initial output in my application based on user-agent parsing... which basically breaks down request rendering so the initial rendering will match the bootstrap sizes of "xs","sm","md","lg" ...

I have my regular expressions worked out so that mobile devices will get output rendered for "xs" and common tablets will get "sm" by default, anyone else gets "md" ... after the client-side binding, it will adjust to the actual device display, this is mainly so that browsers will get the size that they need.

What I want to be able to do is:

- based on a pattern match against the user-agent set a few parameters, that will be passed through (reverse-proxy) to my application

  - `X-Initial-Size` - "xs", "sm", "md", "lg" (realistically nothing will resolve to "lg"
  - `X-Is-Human` - match against known bots for detection
  - `X-Browser-Class` - "ancient", "modern", "ie#" (IE <= 9 only)
- use `X-Initial-Size` and `X-Browser-Class` as `vary-by` params for longer-lived server-side output caching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*- How do I set custom variables based on regexp against a useragent?*

Use a [map](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map). For instance :

```
map $http_user_agent $my_var {
    default     "default_value";
    "~^foo$"    "value_1";
    "~^bar$"    "value_2";
}
```

*- How do I set custom headers for the reverse-proxy request?*

Use [proxy_set_header](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_set_header). For example :

```
proxy_set_header My-Header $my_var;
```

*- How do I use these values as caching parameters?*

Define these additional headers as part of your [proxy cache key](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_cache_key) :

```
proxy_cache_key $scheme$request_uri-$http_my_header-$http_my_other_header
```

Comment: One question, in the regex map, is the `~` part of the regex, or just an indicator to match on a regexp... sorry, I'm not really that familiar with nginx, just wanting to set it up as a reverse-proxy and caching server for my application's rendering.

Also, can the regexp be rather large?  ie, similar to the detectmobilebrowser.com site's matching patterns?

Comment: @Tracker1 It's the symbol recognized by nginx meaning that a regex will follow. This is explained in linked documentation.